# Struct fl has no member named sub

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fl{    
  char sub[3] = {"Math","Science","ICT"};    
};

int main()
{    
    int i;

    struct fl floatp;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i){    
        printf (" %s",floatp.sub[i]);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error "struct fl has no member named sub" on the 11th line. But i do have a member named 'sub'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `char *sub[3] = {"Math","Science","ICT"}; `, but this kind of initialisation is still not correct.

Comment: Your compiler didn't produce an error at the line mentioned by @wildplasser?

Comment: Do not need the `[3]` - use `[]` instead - get the compiler to do the countin

Comment: @wildplasser: To expand on that, *any* initialization of a struct member is not allowed. Anik, is that the only error message you got? You should have gotten an error on the definition of `sub`. And even if that were allowed, `sub` is an array of 3 characters; it can't hold three strings or pointers to strings.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I know.

Comment: @wildplasser: What an awful nickname you've chosen... have you regretted it yet? ;-P

Comment: @wildplasser: My point is that the phrase "this kind of initialisation" might be misunderstood.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes you are right. I should have said something like: there is no object being created, so there cannot be an initialisation.

Comment: @wildplasser: Just to beat this dead horse a bit more, the initializer isn't forbidden because there's no object being created (C++11 permits such initializers with sensible semantics). It's forbidden because C doesn't permit it.

Comment: Note: the question is about C, not C++.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fl {
  char *sub[3];
};

int main()
{
  int i;

  struct fl floatp = {{ "Math","Science","ICT" }};
  // or if your compiler supports it:
  // struct fl floatp = {.sub = { "Math","Science","ICT" }};

  for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    printf(" %s", floatp.sub[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have one question. Why use two curly braces in 9th line?

Comment: Outer for the struct, inner for the array.